# Error in geom_recessions() : could not find function "geom_recessions"

Tags: r

I try to put recession shade on my plot using geom_recessions. But I received error message as follows " Error in geom_recessions() : could not find function "geom_recessions""

My code is as follows: removing the final line geom_recessions(), I can generate plot without problem. But adding it back, the error message would show.

```
a<-rnorm(300)

Date <- seq(as.Date("1910-1-1"), as.Date("1934-12-1"), by="month")

data <- cbind(as.data.frame(Date), a)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Date, y = a, group=1)) +
  geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 2)+
  geom_recessions()
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Please help to resolve this issue or suggest new way to add recession on the plot.

Comment: `geom_recessions` is part of `cmapplot` package. Please see the instructions here to install it https://cmap-repos.github.io/cmapplot/index.html#installation

Comment: I already upvoted the “FAQ” question. So I cannot further add to the effort to get questionnaires in the sense of a person asking a question to some searching on the text of an error message. It would save them so much time, not to mention embarrassment. I still think some recognition of the value of close votes for duplicates would be a favorable design feature.